# Как подключить MongoDB к render.com

Tags: mongodb

Возникла такая проблема. Создал приложение на react, сервер на express, база данных на MongoDB. Локально все работало, юзеры добавлялись, посты добавлялись, изображения добавлялись и сохранялись в папку uploads, все сохранялось в базу данных. После деплоя фронтендной части на netlify, a бекенда на render.com, изображения добавляются, но после перезагрузки сайта они исчезают, хотя в базе данных они есть. Если я правильно понимаю, то я должен как-то связать базу данных и render.com. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

На сайте render.com нашла инструкцию по подключению MongoDb, https://docs.render.com/deploy-mongodb. К сожалению услуга платная.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)